# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Unable to rebuild master database, Cannot shutdown service

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Yesterday I noticed I could not execute any query within the master database.  I tried a DBCC CHECKDB but this just hung (let it run for 24 hours).  I was unable to stop the SQL Server service: "The service cannot accept control messages at this time"

I decided to try to rebuild the master database: setup /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /QUIET /INSTANCENAME=MYINSTANCE /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=MYACCOUNT /SAPWD=MYPASSWORD

Summary.txt seems to indicate the same problem:

```
Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Failed: see details below
  Configuration error code:      0x0A2FBD17@1211@1
  Configuration error description: The service cannot accept control messages at this time.  
  Configuration log:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20140517_091501\Detail.txt
```

It looks like the SQL Server cannot be shutdown.  What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0):

"SHUTDOWN WITH NOWAIT" looks to have fixed the problem.